# Increase y value of SVG drawing using XSLT iteration

Tags: xslt

I asked a similar question earlier. I have made some changes to the code, but am still stuck.

I have part of an XSLT like this:

```
      <xsl:variable name="y" select="0" />
      <xsl:if test="units_display='true'">
          <xsl:call-template name="DisplayBox">
            <xsl:with-param name="current_y" select="$y" />
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="units" />
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Units'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="sensor_display='true'">
          <xsl:call-template name="DisplayBox">
            <xsl:with-param name="current_y" select="$y" />
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="sensor" />
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Type'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="offset_display='true'">
          <xsl:call-template name="DisplayBox">
            <xsl:with-param name="current_y" select="$y" />
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="offset" />
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'Offset'" />
          </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
```

My call-template is like this:

```
<xsl:template name="DisplayBox">
<xsl:param name="current_y" />
<xsl:param name="value" />
<xsl:param name="text" />
  <rect x="20" y="{150 + $current_y}" width="220" height="20" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
  <text x="25" y="{168 + $current_y}" font-family="arial" font-size="20px" fill="black">
    <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
  </text>
  <line x1="90" y1="{150 + $current_y}" x2="90" y2="{170 + $current_y}" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
  <text x="95" y="{168 + $current_y}" font-family="arial" font-size="20px" fill="black"><xsl:value-of select="$text" /></text>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't work out how to increase the value of current_y depending on whether the if statements are true or not. E,g, if a statement is true, the y value needs to be increased by 20, but not if the statement is false.

So the output could be empty if all 3 statements are false or could be any of these permutations:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the whole thing into a recursion template. You are passing $y for "current_y" which has the value "0" into each call of the template. That recursive template would take the same arguments and two additional:

(1) The test to perform for that round of recursion
(2) Whether you have any additional tests to perform (or exit the recursion)

Then you do a choose and increment the "y" (or not) depending on the test.

*** New Info ***

After some more thought based on the comments below, what about using something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="units_display | sensor_display | offset_display">
    <xsl:variable name="y-multiplier">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::units_display[.='true']) + count(preceding-sibling::sensor_display[.='true']) + count(preceding-sibling::offset_display[.='true'])"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:message>
        <xsl:value-of select="$y-multiplier"/>
    </xsl:message>
</xsl:template>
```

This counts all of the elements that meet you criteria as you go through the document. This should get you started toward writing the result without recursion.

Comment: Note, (2) would be optional. If you always know you exit on the test of offset_display, you could just pass in that node and check it's name and exit after it (no recursion).

Comment: I don't understand XSLT very much at all. My application actually has 15 items that may or may not be displayed. In this case, would I need to pass 45 variables to my recursion template (value, test and display for each item). I can do that if that's the only way, it's just so different to procedural (if that's the correct terminology) programming, I can't quite get my head around it

Comment: Without seeing the actual XML you are transforming, it is impossible to guess at other suggestions. Depending on its structure you could make use of a key and possibly count the previous nodes in the key whose value is 'true' and use that to calculate.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I am going to mark your answer as the accepted answer. What I need to do is read a book on XSLT, because I just don't understand this. I've asked about something I really have too little knowledge of. Anyway, thanks for the guidance (which will hopefully make sense in a while)

Comment: Thanks, I though about this a bit more. What you really need to know is the number of "something's" (in your example units_display, sensor_display, offset_display) that are in the XML before. I would believe you could write that in one line in way you have it. Calculating the count of all of the preceding-sibling of those elements that are 'true'. Then use that count as the offset. You could do that without recursion.